# Wordpress List of child pages with thumbnails

Tags: php, wordpress

I am helping a friend create a site, and have hit a snag.

I am attempting to create a List of Child Pages on the Parent page for my site.
Link to parent page: http://www.jonathandavidlange.com/paintings/

I would like the php to grab the Page title, Thumbnail, and make it a link.
Like this: http://www.jonathandavidlange.com/paintings/block-1-ferragosto-the-cafe/

This is turning out to be tougher than I thought. Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => 8)); ?> 

            <?php foreach ($pages as $page): ?>
                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>
                    <h1><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></h1>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

As of right now, the page just returns a single column list of pages, but they are not linked to the page.

Any help you can offer would be excellent.

Thank You,
Ark

**Edit**:

```
    <<?php $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => 8)); ?> 

        <?php foreach ($pages as $page): ?>
            <h1><?php echo $page['post_title'] ?></h1>
            <a href="<?php echo $page['guid'] />"><img src="" /></a>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, you're wondering why none of the page names are links to the page when you haven't actually created links to them?

Comment: J, possibly. I am kinda fumbling my way through PHP as best I can. I'm not really sure how to make it work, which is why I asked the experts after I couldn't find the answer elsewhere already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have no anchor/link.

Here is what you need to do.
Just replace the starred keywords with you variables.

Edit

Leave the image blank as I said the img source is not in the $pages array.

```
<?php $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => 8)); ?> 

      <?php foreach ($pages as $page): ?>
          <h1><?php echo $page['post_title'] ?></h1>
          <a href="<?php echo $page['guid'] ?>"><img src="" /></a>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Hmm. I am still a bit new, but I was wanting it to make all of the pages links. That code looks like it will just make 1 image a link right?

I am trying to have it grab all of the pages under the parent, and create linked images from the thumbnails.

Comment: Since the code is wrapped inside a foreach it will execute multiple times. The amount time it executes depends how many pages exists in the pages array.

Comment: OH! Ok, then I guess I confused what variables I would give. When you say, [title] do you mean 'post_title' ?

Comment: Yes you have to replace title, page_url, img_source with the actual names of the variables that should be contained in the pages array.

Comment: Ok. So I make sure I am getting this right then. In order my variables should be: 'post_title', www.jonathandavidlange.com/paintings, get_the_post_thumbnail

Comment: I don't know the structure of $pages array. To find-out remove the foreach code and just do print($pages). This will show all the data contained in the $pages array. You can use to figure what variables to use.

Comment: Hrm...Ok, I think I have most of it figured out. Still unsure what I would put in [page_url]. could you help me a little more with that?

Comment: Did you do print_r($pages) ? Looks for urls and see which variable its associated with.

Comment: I am really sorry. I don't know what that means. I will post my code above as an edit to my original. Maybe that will help.

Comment: I meant like this  <<?php $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => 8));  print_r($pages)?>

Comment: Soo, what am I looking for in all that?

Comment: Yep that's what I wanted, it looks the url is contained within a varaible guid. So [page_url] should be guid.

Comment: See my edit to the code in my original question. Is it correct now?

Comment: "post_title" is correct, "page_guid" should be just "guid" and thumbnail does not exists in the pages array.

Comment: See my edited code. Causes the page not to work. Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Hmm, still returns a broke page.

Comment: There was a small typo, just changed. Try again.

Comment: Ok, page actually appears. But it is blank.

Comment: Oh, that's too bad. There is not much more I can do.

Comment: Damn. Well, I really appreciate all your help. Can I buy you a pizza? Thanks.

Comment: There is no need people on here helped me out when I was starting not to long ago.